# "New Thread" and Async

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I did a sample to simulate concurrency using the code below:

```
var threads = new Thread[200]; 
//starting threads logic
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
         {
             threads[i].Start();
         }
         for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
         {
             threads[i].Join();
         }
```

The code is supposed to insert thousands of records to the database and it seems to work well, as the threads finished at almost the same time.

But, when I use:

```
 var tasks = new List<Task<int>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(insert(i));
            //   await insert(i);
        }
        int[] result = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

it takes a lot of time to finish the same logic.

Can someone explain to me what's the difference? I thought that `Await` should create threads.

Comment: No. await does NOT create Threads. http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html The word Async has nothing to do with Multithreading at all in this context.

Comment: Where in code do you *start* your tasks ?

Comment: Are you aware that starting a thread consumes over 1MB of memory? So 200 is well over 200MB. And that's without doing any processing. And starting threads is slow. It's far far better to use them from the thread-pool.

Comment: thanks guys , really your replies are helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to replicate your original `Thread`-based behaviour, you can use `Task.Factory.StartNew(... , TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)` to schedule your work, and then block until the worker tasks complete via `Task.WaitAll`. I do not recommended this approach, but in terms of behaviour this will be very close to how your code was working previously.

A more in-depth analysis as to why may not getting the expected performance in your scenario is as follows:

**Explanation, part 1** (`async` does not mean "on a different thread")

Methods marked with the `async` keyword do not magically run asynchronously. They are merely *capable* of combining awaitable operations (that may or may not run asynchronously themselves), into a single larger unit (generally `Task` or `Task<T>`).

If your `insert` method is `async`, it is still likely that it performs at least *some* of the work synchronously. This will definitely be the case with *all* of your code preceding the first `await` statement. This work will execute on the "main" thread (thread which calls `insert`) - and that will be your bottleneck or at least part thereof as the degree of parallelism for that section of your code will be 1 while you're calling `insert` in a tight loop, regardless of whether you `await` the resulting task.

To illustrate the above point, consider the following example:

```
void Test()
{
    Debug.Print($"Kicking off async chain (thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}) - this is the main thread");
    OuterTask().Wait(); // Do not block on Tasks - educational purposes only.
}

async Task OuterTask()
{
    Debug.Print($"OuterTask before await (thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId})");
    await InnerTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
    Debug.Print($"OuterTask after await (thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId})");
}

async Task InnerTask()
{
    Debug.Print($"InnerTask before await (thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId})");
    await Task.Delay(10).ConfigureAwait(false);
    Debug.Print($"InnerTask after await (thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}) - we are now on the thread pool");
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
Kicking off async chain (thread 6) - this is the main thread
OuterTask before await (thread 6)
InnerTask before await (thread 6)
InnerTask after await (thread 8) - we are now on the thread pool
OuterTask after await (thread 8)
```

Note that the code before the first `await` inside `Task1` and even `Task2` still executes on the "main" thread. Our chain actually executes synchronously, on the same thread which kicked off the outer task, until we `await` the first truly async operation (in this case `Task.Delay`).

*Additionally*

If you are running in an environment where `SynchronizationContext.Current` is not null (i.e. Windows Forms, WPF) and you're not using `ConfigureAwait(false)` on the tasks awaited inside your `insert` method, then continuations scheduled by the async state machine *after* the first `await` statement will *also* likely execute on the "main" thread - although this is not guaranteed in certain environments (i.e. ASP.NET).

**Explanation, part 2** (executing `Task`s on the thread pool)

If, as part of your `insert` method, you are opting to start any `Task`s manually, then you are most likely scheduling your work on the thread pool by using `Task.Run` or *any other* method of starting a new task that does not specify `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`. Once the thread pool gets saturated any newly started tasks will be queued, thus reducing the throughput of your parallel system.

*Proof:*

```
IEnumerable<Task> tasks = Enumerable
    .Range(0, 200)
    .Select(_ => Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(100))); // Using Thread.Sleep to simulate blocking calls.

await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // Completes in 2+ seconds.
```

Now with `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`:

```
IEnumerable<Task> tasks = Enumerable
    .Range(0, 200)
    .Select(_ => Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () => Thread.Sleep(100), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning
    ));

await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // Completes in under 130 milliseconds.
```

It is generally *not* a good idea to spawn 200 threads (this will not scale well), but if massive parallelisation of blocking calls is an absolute requirement, the above snippet shows you one way to do it with TPL.

Comment: thanks , really your reply is helpful

Answer (score 0):

In first example you created threads manually. In second you created tasks. Task - probably - are using thread pool, where limited count of threads exist. So, most task ae waiting in queue, while few of them are executing in parallel on available threads.

Comment: Tasks (Await/Async) [do not create or use theads](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html), it is only a very complex state machine.

Comment: @Erik Of course, but tasks are executing using threads. TaskSheduker manage tasks, and use threads from thread pool to execute them. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997402%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: thanks guys , really your replies are helpful